# JPA: globally changing type of the database column generated in schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, varchar

We are generating our database schema using JPA, using this property set in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

But it turned out that varchar column type generated by JPA for our String properties is too short. I know we can add:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(2000)")
String someStr;
```

For every String property of our entities but it would be a lot of work.

It would be much better to globally configure JPA in the way that it generates varchar(2000) for every String in our entities. Is this possible?

PS. We use Hibernate as JPA backend if this fact matters.

Comment: A. you could change the length of column only for the properties which make trouble                     
B. If you need it for all properties, I would close my eyes, imagine I am on my happy place and in some editor just replaced every occurence of @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar") with @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(2000)") under the root of your project. It is unlikely that it is used anywhere else than in column definition

Comment: you can write your own annotation